# Add Reference pointing to a different version than GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, db2, asp.net-3.5, gac

In one of my websites, I have added a reference to IBM.DATA.DB2.dll (which is in GAC, version 9.0.0.2) as shown in the text below from web.config:-

But when I build my project, it tries to point it to a different version of the dll, as shown below in the error mrssage:-

"Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I checked in GAC (C://Windows/Assemblies) and I cannot see any reference to version 9.7.4.4 there. I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Thanks,
Abhi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using fuslogvw.exe. From the log I found out that there was a version redirect in the machine.config file in path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config", which was redirecting the reference 9.0.0.2 to 9.7.4.4.

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="IBM.Data.DB2" publicKeyToken="7c307b91aa13d208" culture="" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.0.0.0-9.0.0.4" newVersion="9.7.7.4" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Changing 9.7.4.4 to 9.0.0.2 solved the probem.

Thanks,
Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "specific version" property set to `true`? Does it need to be that version? If you can link to any version then set that property to `false`. This will allow your project to link to any version of the assembly.

It could also be a dependency of a one of your other dependencies that's pulling in this particular version.

If you do need the older version and the newer is being pulled in by some other reference then you've got a different problem. This can only be solved by upgrading your application or finding a version of the 3<sup>rd</sup> assembly that references the older version too.

Double check to see if you've got the latest version (it doesn't look like it if you have version 9.0.0.2 and Visual Studio is looking for version 9.7.4.4). Download and install that version.